# Rest URL consumption guidance required

Tags: c#, rest

I have a rest url provided by client , It looks something like **www.baseurl/api//** I couldn't get result if I try to consume it from console application getting error 503.
However I m able to browse it from my browser and it returns the proper json of Entity Details. Please help me with this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp15
{

    public class Class1
    {
        private const string URL = "www.baseurl/api/<EntityName>/<EntityID>";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1.CreateObject();
        }

        private static void CreateObject()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            try
            {
                WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream() ?? Stream.Null)
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                {
                    string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("-----------------");
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: 503 stands for `Service Unavailable`. Either the URL is wrong (I'm looking at "www.baseurl/api/<EntityName>/<EntityID>") or the service is, indeed, unavailable. Where do you replace the <EntityName> and <EntityID> ?

Comment: I replace it before assigning the URL itself .

Comment: Are you missing any headers? X-Accept, for example? Is the Content-Type in accordance to what the docs specify it needs to be? Other than that, I'd inspect the chrome developer console (F12) and check the Network tab to see what was sent differently from your code.